# Problem with recursive search of xml document using python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to write a function that will take an xml object, an arbitrary number of tags, defined by tuples containing a tag name, attribute and attribute value (e.g ('tag1', 'id', '1')) and return the most specific node possible.  My code is below:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def _search(object, *pargs):
    if len(pargs) == 0:
        print "length of pargs was zero"
        return object
    else:
        print "length of pargs is %s" % len(pargs)
    if pargs[0][1]:
        for element in object.getElementsByTagName(pargs[0][0]):
            if element.attributes[pargs[0][1]].value == pargs[0][2]:
                _search(element, *pargs[1:])
    else:
        if object.getElementsByTagName(pargs[0][0]) == 1:
            _search(element, *pargs[1:])
def main():
    xmldoc = minidom.parse('./example.xml')
    tag1 = ('catalog_item', 'gender', "Men's")
    tag2 = ('size', 'description', 'Large')
    tag3 = ('color_swatch', '', '')

    args = (tag1, tag2, tag3)
    node = _search(xmldoc, *args)
    node.toxml()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.  Here's the output when I run the script:

```
$ ./secondsearch.py
length of pargs is 3
length of pargs is 2
length of pargs is 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./secondsearch.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "./secondsearch.py", line 32, in main
    node.toxml()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toxml'
```

Why isn't the 'if len(pargs) == 0' clause being exercised?  If I do manage to get the xml object returned to my main method, can I then pass the object into some other function (which could change the value of the node, or append a child node, etc.)?

Background: Using python to automate testing processes, environment is is cygwin on winxp/vista/7, python version is 2.5.2.  I would prefer to stay within the standard library if at all possible.

**Here's the working code**:

```
def _search(object, *pargs):
    if len(pargs) == 0:
        print "length of pargs was zero"
    else:
        print "length of pargs is %s" % len(pargs)
    for element in object.getElementsByTagName(pargs[0][0]):
        if pargs[0][1]:
            if element.attributes[pargs[0][1]].value == pargs[0][2]:
                return _search(element, *pargs[1:])
        else:
            if object.getElementsByTagName(pargs[0][0]) == 1:
                return _search(element, *pargs[1:])
    return object
```

Comment: Your code seems to have been flattened; you should probably fix it so people can run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/17/10084853/xml-viewer.aspx as your sample data...

As [Vinay pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157768/problem-with-recursive-search-of-xml-document-using-python/1157787#1157787), you don't return anything from your recursive calls to`_search`.

In your else case, you don't define the value of element, but you pass it into the `_search()`.

Also, you don't do anything if `pargs[0][1]` is empty, but `object.getElementsByTagName(pargs[0][0])` returns more than one Node... (which is also why your pargs == 0 case never gets hit...)

And after all that, if that sample data is correct, there are two matching nodes. so you'll have a NodeList containing:

```
        <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
        <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
```

and you can't call `.toxml()` on a NodeList...

Comment: Thanks.  You made several valid points, all of which I kept in mind as I rewrote the function.  The only one not represented in the code itself is the section dealing with a NodeList being returned - that got a comment in my script reminding me to include enough information to obtain a specific node.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be inserting a **return** in front of your recursive calls to `_search`? The way you have it now, some exit paths from `_search` don't have a `return` statement, so they will return `None` - which leads to the exception you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'inserting a return in front of your recursive calls', specifically 'in front of'.  Could you explain that more fully?

Comment: Yes - your statement should be

return _search(element, *pargs[1:])

rather than just

_search(element, *pargs[1:])

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm giving Stobor the solution, but I did up your score to reflect your significant assistance.  Again, thanks.